# Best methods with working with integers?

Tags: c++, vector, int

I have few a question regarding techniques involving working with integers and overall coding.

For example, if I have to modify or check integer numbers, I save the digits of a number in a vector and then work with them and then if necessary put them back together, however, I think it's a bit impractical.

There was a task where I had to write a function that removes zeros from an integer and returns the same number without the zeros.

```
int removeZeros(int n) {
    std::vector<int> v;

    while(n != 0) {
        v.push_back(n%10);
        n /= 10;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        if(v[i] == 0) {
            v.erase(v.begin() + i);
            i--;
        }
    }

    for(int i = v.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        n *= 10;
        n += v[i];
    }
    return n;
}
```

This code works good, however I am not sure whether it's "written" well, efficient.

Do you think the method this method is good, efficient enough? or is there a better, more convenient way to work with (or modify) integers?

Can you hand me any tips on how to be a more efficient coder?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about coding style are more appropriate for CodeReview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without using `vector`s at all - just maths.

```
long int NoZeros(long int num) {
    bool sign = num < 0;

    long int ret = 0, running = 1;
    while (num) {
        if (num % 10) {
            ret += running * (num % 10);
            running *= 10;
        }
        num /= 10;
    }
    return sign?-num:num;
}
```